# mongo morphia howto Safely remove a string from a String array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, morphia

ok I have this (beginner again)
.

```
// ADD FRIEND TO FRIEND LIST   
Query<FriendList> query1 = mongo.createQuery(FriendList.class);   
query1.field("lowerCaseUserName").equal(on.lowerCaseUserName);  
query1.field("passwordHash").equal(on.passwordHash);
query1.field("uuid").equal(on.uuid);
UpdateOperations<FriendList>up1=mongo.createUpdateOperations(FriendList.class).add("friendList",buddyUuid,false);
```

Im inserting a friend into the `Array`. The "friendList" is a `String Array`.
Would like to be able to implement removal now.

Can i just write the same code and replace the "`.add`" with removexxx...something?
Im thinking it's a good ide but maybe not :)

```
@Entity
public class FriendList {

    @Id private ObjectId id;

    public Date lastAccessedDate;

    @Indexed(name="uuid", unique=true,dropDups=true)  
    private String uuid;

    @Indexed(value=IndexDirection.ASC, name="lowerCaseUserName", unique=true,dropDups=true)  
    public String lowerCaseUserName;

    public String passwordHash = "";

    List<String> friendList;

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public List<String> getFriendList() {
        return friendList;
    }

    public void insertFriend(String friend) {
        this.friendList.add(friend);
    }
//  @PrePersist void prePersist() {
//      lastAccessedDate = new Date();
//  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Query<FriendList> query1 = mongo.createQuery(FriendList.class);   
query1.field("lowerCaseUserName").equal(on.lowerCaseUserName);  
query1.field("passwordHash").equal(on.passwordHash);
query1.field("uuid").equal(on.uuid);
UpdateOperations<FriendList>up1=mongo.createUpdateOperations(FriendList.class).removeAll("friendList",buddyUuid);
```

This should remove the `buddyUuid` from the list.

If you could guarantee that the `friendList` contains unique UUID's then you could use `removeFirst || removeLast` method.

[removeFirst/Last/All](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Updating#removeFirst/Last/All)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks. I was unsure about this because the example dont show how the "updateQuery" is constructed. I have tested this now and it works grate.